# contact sharing settings giving controlled by parent

Tags: apex, community

Trying to make an app survey available to external users through "sites". Site is already created and active but for contact sharing settings,

It says "controlled by parent" and cannot be edited. Who is parent and how do we edit.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the below link. For contact Parent is Account.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004005&language=en_US

To address this you can either set up an Account sharing rule to share the Accounts the Contacts are related to, or you can change the Org Wide Default for Contacts to a value other than "Controlled by parent" ('Private' or 'Public Read-Only', for example) so that the Contact Sharing Rules will apply.

Regards,
Sfdcdev.

Answer (score 1):

Also please note that if you have person accounts enabled then you will not be able to change the contact settings. It will be grayed out.

Once you are using PersonAccounts, Contact sharing has to be controlled by the Account record (since with a PersonAccount, they are treated as a single record)